# Google Analytics deserialization with Gson is returning LinkedTreeMap

Tags: android, google-analytics, gson, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to pass an object containing Analytics Reporting data in an Intent via a broadcast. The problem is the deserialization which returns a LinkedTreeMap instead of the original serialized object, causing a crash with ClassCastException.
I tried to follow quite all answers found here on SO, from using TypeToken to modify ProGuard rules and nothing worked.

I thought to implement Parcelable interface but the problem is that I have an inner private AsyncTask class where the data is collected and pushed into the intent which will be sent via broadcast.

Here is the code of the helper where data is serialized:

```
public class AnalyticsHelper 
{
    ...

    private class GoogleBatchTask extends AsyncTask<GetReportsRequest,Void,GetReportsResponse>
    {   
        @Override 
        protected GetReportsResponse doInBackground(@NonNull GetReportsRequest... reports)
        {   
            GetReportsResponse response = null;

            try {
                if (m_reports == null)
                    return null;
                response = m_reports.reports().batchGet(reports[0]).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Console.log(e);
            }

            return response;
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(GetReportsResponse response)
        {   
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("com.keyone.contactpackapp.ANALYTICS_DATA");
            intent.putExtra("response", new Gson().toJson(response));

            Context context = PackConfig.instance().context();
            if (context == null)
                return;

            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

AnalyticsFragment.java, where the deserialization happens:

```
public class AnalyticsFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        // Listen to custom intent with data
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.keyone.contactpackapp.ANALYTICS_DATA");

        m_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                // Get data from intent and pass it to the right fragment
                String szJson = intent.getStringExtra("response");

                //m_response = new Gson().fromJson(szJson, GetReportsResponse.class);
                Type listType = new TypeToken<GetReportsResponse>(){}.getType();
                m_response = new Gson().fromJson(szJson, listType);

                Fragment fragment = m_activity.currentFragment();
                fragment.updateData();
            }
        };

        if (m_activity != null)
            m_activity.registerReceiver(m_receiver, filter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way to deserialize object in a correct way using Gson neither using Java Serializable interface or Android Parcelable interface due to the nature of the objects to serialize.

So I opted to call an instance of the recipient class and pass object data through a method in it